# node.js axios download file stream and writeFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

i want download a pdf file with `axios` and save on disk (server side) with `fs.writeFile`, i have tried:

```
axios.get('https://xxx/my.pdf', {responseType: 'blob'}).then(response => {
    fs.writeFile('/temp/my.pdf', response.data, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('The file has been saved!');
    });
});
```

the file is saved but the content is broken...

how do I correctly save the file?

Comment: you get the console log "The file has been saved" and the file is created and just the content is wrong?

Comment: where you are calling axios.get ? it will not wait for the file to be written. better promisify the fs or use fs-extra or use promisfied methods from fs. and use like return fs.writeFile(...)

Comment: @RolandStarke yes, the file is saved

Comment: I've posted a more cleaner approach to solve the problem using node stream pipelines below. It's on the same concept which the accepted answer proposes.

stackoverflow.com/a/64925465/3476378

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Actually, I believe the previously accepted answer has some flaws, as it will not handle the writestream properly, so if you call "then()" after Axios has given you the response, you will end up having a partially downloaded file.

This is a more appropriate solution when downloading slightly larger files:

```
export async function downloadFile(fileUrl: string, outputLocationPath: string) {
  const writer = createWriteStream(outputLocationPath);

  return Axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: fileUrl,
    responseType: 'stream',
  }).then(response => {

    //ensure that the user can call `then()` only when the file has
    //been downloaded entirely.

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      response.data.pipe(writer);
      let error = null;
      writer.on('error', err => {
        error = err;
        writer.close();
        reject(err);
      });
      writer.on('close', () => {
        if (!error) {
          resolve(true);
        }
        //no need to call the reject here, as it will have been called in the
        //'error' stream;
      });
    });
  });
}
```

This way, you can call `downloadFile()`, call `then()` on the returned promise, and making sure that the downloaded file will have completed processing.

Or, if you use a more modern version of NodeJS, you can try this instead:

```
import * as stream from 'stream';
import { promisify } from 'util';

const finished = promisify(stream.finished);

export async function downloadFile(fileUrl: string, outputLocationPath: string): Promise<any> {
  const writer = createWriteStream(outputLocationPath);
  return Axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: fileUrl,
    responseType: 'stream',
  }).then(response => {
    response.data.pipe(writer);
    return finished(writer); //this is a Promise
  });
}
```

Comment: This is correct and solves exactly the problem related to Partial data error

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. it fixed the partial download error

Comment: I've posted a more cleaner approach on the same concept of your using stream pipelines below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64925465/3476378.

Comment: It's better to register close and error event handlers before piping the response stream on the write stream.

Comment: Does this wait for the file to be completely downloaded before starting to write using `writer`? Ie, that doesn't seem like it is really streaming read to write in that case as it's waiting for one to finish before the other begins.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. As bytes are downloaded, they are being streamed to a file, and once all bytes have been streamed, the Promise ends, and the rest of the application flow continues. The 'then' in the example is called before the file has finished downloading - check the documentation about the `stream` responseType of axios.

Comment: good, but, why not use await ? (await axios .... followed by pipe, and finaly return the promise returned by finished, there are no cases where you have to use then, and only very few cases where you need explicit promises (mostly to wrap old code)

Comment: response.data.pipe is not a function

Comment: A very good answer, worked for me after hours of searching.

Comment: There are easier ways nowadays. Scroll down!

Comment: This gives a `Uncaught TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function
    at promisify (util.js:613:1)` error...

Answer (score 94):

You can simply use `response.data.pipe` and `fs.createWriteStream` to pipe response to file

```
axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "https://xxx/my.pdf",
    responseType: "stream"
}).then(function (response) {
    response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("/temp/my.pdf"));
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Was looking for this forever

Comment: This answer is not complete, because when you download some larger files, the pipe will give you more than one events. This code does not wait until the whole file has been downloaded before one can call `then` on it. Take a look at my solution to find what I consider a more complete solution.

Comment: response.data.pipe is not a function

Comment: if to not download file on local storage then how to do that i tried res.sendFile in node.js

Comment: To critique this solution, you **must** set the responseType to "stream".  Not doing so will cause an error when you try to pipe it to another stream.

Answer (score 35):

The problem with broken file is because of ***backpressuring in node streams***. You may find this link useful to read: https://nodejs.org/es/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/

I'm not really a fan of using Promise base declarative objects in JS codes as I feel it pollutes the actual core logic & makes the code hard to read. On top of it, you have to provision event handlers & listeners to make sure the code is completed.

A more cleaner approach on the same logic which the accepted answer proposes is given below. It uses the concepts of ***stream pipelines***.

```
const util = require('util');
const stream = require('stream');
const pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline);

const downloadFile = async () => {
  try {
    const request = await axios.get('https://xxx/my.pdf', {
      responseType: 'stream',
    });
    await pipeline(request.data, fs.createWriteStream('/temp/my.pdf'));
    console.log('download pdf pipeline successful');   
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('download pdf pipeline failed', error);
  }
}

exports.downloadFile = downloadFile
```

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Why response type blob and not stream?

Comment: I get "stream.on is not a function" error with this method

Comment: I got it working like this: 
const resp = await axios.get(....);
await pipeline(resp.data, fs.createWriteStream(...))

Comment: @1252748 blob is a browser only option.

Answer (score 14):

The following code taken from [https://gist.github.com/senthilmpro/072f5e69bdef4baffc8442c7e696f4eb?permalink_comment_id=3620639#gistcomment-3620639](https://%20%20%20%20const%20result%20=%20await%20axios.get(url_to_download,%20%7B%20responseType:%20%27arraybuffer%27%20%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fs.writeFileSync(filename,%20result.data);) worked for me

```
const res = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
fs.writeFileSync(downloadDestination, res.data);
```

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't want to use streams since I need to upload this file to my cloud!

Answer (score 12):

```
// This works perfectly well! 
const axios = require('axios'); 

axios.get('http://www.sclance.com/pngs/png-file-download/png_file_download_1057991.png', {responseType: "stream"} )  
.then(response => {  
// Saving file to working directory  
    response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("todays_picture.png"));  
})  
    .catch(error => {  
    console.log(error);  
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You may want to provide a bit of explanation to go along with your code sample.

Comment: this is not going to work properly, as it will not wait until the file has finished downloading before continuing the promise chain.

Answer (score 6):

node fileSystem `writeFile` encodes data by default to UTF8. which could be a problem in your case.

Try setting your encoding to `null` and skip encoding the received data:

```
fs.writeFile('/temp/my.pdf', response.data, {encoding: null}, (err) => {...}
```

you can also decalre encoding as a string (instead of options object) if you only declare encoding and no other options. string will be handled as encoding value. as such:

```
fs.writeFile('/temp/my.pdf', response.data, 'null', (err) => {...}
```

more read in [fileSystem API write_file](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

Comment: @double-beep tnx for your comment. i've edited with some explanation and read material from `node fileSystem API` about writeFile function. :)

Answer (score 5):

There is a much simpler way that can be accomplished in a couple of lines:

```js
import fs from 'fs';

const fsPromises = fs.promises;

const fileResponse = await axios({
    url: fileUrl,
    method: "GET",
    responseType: "stream",
});

// Write file to disk (here I use fs.promise but you can use writeFileSync it's equal
await fsPromises.writeFile(filePath, fileResponse.data);
```

`Axios` has internal capacity of handling `streams` and you don't need to necessarily meddle with low-level Node APIs for that.

Check out https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config (find the `responseType` part in the docs for all the types you can use).

Comment: What is fsPromises?

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clearer. Thank you!

Comment: I am trying to wrap my head around it. Why don't we need pipeline in this case? How does this avoid pipeline but regular `createWriteStream` doesn't? Is this still only writing to file without saving any backpressuring-related data to memory?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but my best guess is axios is handling all of that under the hood.

Comment: From the docs: "fsPromises.writeFile is a convenience method that performs multiple write calls internally to write the buffer passed to it. **For performance sensitive code consider using fs.createWriteStream() or filehandle.createWriteStream().**" https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromiseswritefilefile-data-options

Comment: Yeah not all apps need such an incredible performance. I would bet axios would work fine for at least 95% of the use cases! :)

Answer (score 3):

I have tried, and I'm sure that using `response.data.pipe` and `fs.createWriteStream` can work.

---

Besides, I want to add my situation and solution

Situation:

- using `koa` to develop a node.js server
- using `axios` to get a pdf via url
- using `pdf-parse` to parse the pdf
- extract some information of pdf and return it as json to browser

Solution:

```js
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();
const axios = require('axios')
const fs = require("fs")
const pdf = require('pdf-parse');
const utils = require('./utils')

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
      let url = 'https://path/name.pdf'
      let resp = await axios({
          url: encodeURI(url),
          responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        })

        let data = await pdf(resp.data)

        ctx.body = {
            phone: utils.getPhone(data.text),
            email: utils.getEmail(data.text),
        }
})
```

In this solution, it doesn't need to write file and read file, it's more efficient.

Comment: How is buffering the entire data file in memory before sending it "more efficient" than streaming it?

Comment: I don't get your point? What do you mean by saying "sending"? In my situation, I only need to parse pdf file, no need to respond

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the file use this

```
const media_data =await axios({url: url, method: "get",  responseType: "arraybuffer"})
writeFile("./image.jpg", Buffer.from(media_data.data), {encoding: "binary"}, console.log)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me and it also creates a temporary file for the image file in case the output file path is not specified:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const axios = require('axios').default
const tmp = require('tmp');

const downloadFile = async (fileUrl, outputLocationPath) => {
    if(!outputLocationPath) {
        outputLocationPath = tmp.fileSync({ mode: 0o644, prefix: 'kuzzle-listener-', postfix: '.jpg' });
    }
    let path = typeof outputLocationPath === 'object' ? outputLocationPath.name : outputLocationPath
    const writer = fs.createWriteStream(path)
    const response = await axios.get(fileUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(response.data instanceof Buffer) {
            writer.write(response.data)
            resolve(outputLocationPath.name)
        } else {
            response.data.pipe(writer)
            let error = null
            writer.on('error', err => {
                error = err
                writer.close()
                reject(err)
            })
            writer.on('close', () => {
                if (!error) {
                    resolve(outputLocationPath.name)
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Here is a very simple Jest test:

```
it('when downloadFile should downloaded', () => {
    downloadFile('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HhpbzPMCKDc/hq720.jpg').then((file) => {
        console.log('file', file)
        expect(file).toBeTruthy()
        expect(file.length).toBeGreaterThan(10)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Lorenzo's response is probably the best answer as it's using the axios built-in.
Here's a simple way to do it if you just want the buffer:

```js
const downloadFile = url => axios({ url, responseType: 'stream' })
  .then(({ data }) => {
    const buff = []
    data.on('data', chunk => buff.push(chunk))
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      data.on('error', reject)
      data.on('close', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(buff)))
    })
  })

// better
const downloadFile = url => axios({ url, responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(res => res.data)

const res = await downloadFile(url)
fs.writeFileSync(downloadDestination, res)
```

I'd still probably use the 'arraybuffer' responseType

Answer (score -3):

```
import download from "downloadjs";

export const downloadFile = async (fileName) => {
    axios({
        method: "get",
        url: `/api/v1/users/resume/${fileName}`,
        responseType: "blob",
    }).then(function (response) {
        download(response.data, fileName);
    });
};
```

it's work fine to me

Answer (score -4):

This is my example code run with node js
There is a synctax error

should be **writeFile** not **WriteFile**

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
axios.get('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf', {responseType: 'blob'}).then(response => {
  fs.writeFile('./my.pdf', response.data, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('The file has been saved!');
    });
});
```

After the file is saved it might look like in a text editor, but the file was saved properly

```
%PDF-1.3
%����

1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Outlines
/Count 0
>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Count 2
/Kids [ 4 0 R 6 0 R ] 
>>
endobj
```

Comment: How is this an answer?  You have not explained anything that is different from what the OP posted.