# How to stop a writestream from creating a file when receiving 403 error with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, axios, createwritestream

I'm using axios to download images and save them locally. I took the below answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61269447/7468791 which works great for larger images to make sure they have fully downloaded before writing.

However some image urls are returning a 403 error. I'm still getting an image file created for these albeit an empty file. How could I tweak the code so that if the get request receives a 403 error it will not try to write anything?

```
export async function downloadFile(fileUrl: string, outputLocationPath: string) {
const writer = createWriteStream(outputLocationPath);

return Axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: fileUrl,
  responseType: 'stream',
}).then(response => {

  //ensure that the user can call `then()` only when the file has
  //been downloaded entirely.

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    response.data.pipe(writer);
    let error = null;
    writer.on('error', err => {
      error = err;
      writer.close();
      reject(err);
    });
    writer.on('close', () => {
      if (!error) {
        resolve(true);
      }
      //no need to call the reject here, as it will have been called in the
      //'error' stream;
    });
  });
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The response code should be available in response.status, and you can then check and conditionally reject the promise.

Comment: sorry for late reply and thanks for your reply! I did try getting the response status and outputting it to the console as a test. 200 statuses were printing the status code but 403 statuses were not. I'll revisit my code :)