# How to get an image of the highcharts chart in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, highcharts

With highcharts, we have a built-in button to download the current chart (example: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/, this button: arrow). We can save it as PNG, JPEG, PDF or SVG.

Instead of downloading it on client side i want to download image on server and sent that image to particular user through email How could I do that using Node.js ?

[image]

I got this solution, but getting **TypeError: chartExporter.export is not a function**:-

```
const fs = require("fs");
const chartExporter = require("highcharts-export-server");

chartExporter.initPool();

let chartOptions = highchart chart option

chartExporter.export({
    type: "svg",
    outfile: "./output-file.svg",
    options: chartOptions
}, (err, res) => {
    console.log(`The chart has been succesfully generated as SVG at ${res.filename}!`);

    chartExporter.killPool();
});
```

How to resolve this issue or anyone has any other solution to fulfil my requirement

**

> Note :- Below solution is working for me but got this error when i try
> to get image second time

**

[image]

Comment: It is a timeout that means there is insufficient amount to process the data, are you having too much series data in the chart? For a quick test create an html file with the highchart codes and open in browser see how much time it takes to render

Comment: working for first time If i try to get image but after 2-3 times it's not working with same highchart series data

Comment: It should not working any time if it's series data issue

Comment: Try to increase the worker count and timeout `options.pool.minWorkers = 10`  `options.pool.maxWorkers = 20` `options.pool.createTimeout = 120000``options.pool.acquireTimeout = 120000`. More [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-export-server)

Comment: Everything working fine in local but when all code deployed on server it's not working, I've implement email functionality -> downloading highchart chart image and sent it into email

Comment: Getting this error :- **In pool.postWork: [pool] Error when acquiring available entry: Error** in startExport inside function err parameter

Comment: Nodejs/npm versions must be different on local vs on server. Or it could be permission issue try to resolve it with chmod

Comment: I think i'm facing issue in kubernetes, it doesn't allow to create folder like this so can you please give solution to restrict tmp folder creation

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of any solution I request you to go to the [github page](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server) of this package and open a ticket (in "issues" section) explaining your problem probably the author can help

Comment: Is there any other package or library to download highchart chart image , where i can download image without folder creation process, please suggest other way to download highchart image with example

Comment: [other way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802528/how-to-save-an-image-of-the-chart-on-the-server-with-highcharts) I found one solution but how can i implement this solution with node js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got some wrong documentation the name of function is `startExport`
Please try the code below

```
const exporter = require('highcharts-export-server');
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

async function run() {
    const data = {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
        series: [{
            name: 'Los Angeles',
            data: [6, 7, 7, 7, 6]
        },{
            name: 'London',
            data: [3, 4, 3, 4, 3]
        }]
    };

    const exportSettings = {
        export: {
            type: 'png',
            options: {
                chart: {
                    type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'My Chart'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: data.categories
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                    }
                },
                series: data.series
            }
        }
    };

    const options = exporter.setOptions(exportSettings);

    await exporter.initPool(options);

    exporter.startExport(exportSettings, function (res, err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error in exporting chart:', err);
            return;
        }
        const binaryData = Buffer.from(res.data, 'base64');
        exporter.killPool();

        const savepath = path.join(__dirname, './', 'output.png')
        fs.writeFile(savepath, binaryData, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error in writing to image file:', err);
                return;
            }
            console.log('File written successfully.');
        });
    });
}

run()
```

**UPDATE:**

To prevent log creation you can set the logging level to 0 in the `options` object (result of `setOptions`)

```
    const options = exporter.setOptions(exportSettings);
    options.logging.level = 0
```

Regarding the `tmp` folder, it is used by highcharts-export-server to keep the temp files and resources generated during processing but unfortunately the package does not offer a way to change the location of tmp folder as of now (although a pending PR is there in the official github repo so keep an eye on it)

Comment: But I've one question, after applying this code log and tmp named two folder created with some files and added more files when call run() function. so i just want to know reason behind this process

Comment: Those are logs created automatically by the chart export package so developer can debug in case of any issue. I guess there is some option you can pass to disable that

Comment: `tmp` and `log` folder can be safely removed using `fs.unlink`

Comment: Vinay mentioned please if you have any solution to disabled of creation logs and tmp folder, So developer can manage it as per requirement

Comment: See my update in the answer

Comment: I got this error Error in exporting chart: In pool.postWork: [pool] Error when acquiring available entry: Error: operation timed out for an unknown reason

Comment: when I export chart image single time and try to export one more time

Comment: Please post a new question with a the code sample which is giving the error

Comment: Vinay I've update quetion with error description and  image of error , let me know if you have any solution for this error

Comment: highcharts-export-server create two folders tmp and log during chart image download process, with the help of using options.logging.level = 0 can prevent log creation folder but I want to prevent tmp folder creation becuase kubernetes does not allow folder creation, so let me know if any solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

According to your description,

> Instead of downloading it on client side i want to download image on
> server

So your requirement is to fetch the image in to your NodeJS backend app and then send the image to the frontend/client.

To achieve this, you need to make HTTP request from you NodeJS application to highcharts and you can use [AXIOS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or [NodeJS HTTP module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html). Once you get the image into your application the second part is to send the image to your client. There are main two possible scenarios to do this as below,

1. Send image link to the client (For this you need to store image somewhere)
2. Send Base64 encoded image data to the client (You do not have to store the image anywhere)

Comment: No I just want to download particular highchart charts image in my node js server and send that image to particular user

Comment: So how can i download png of highchart charts in node js server ??

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, you can use the AXIOS node module to download the image. You can find many ways in the internet to download the image.

Comment: I think download png of highcharts chart with the help of using node-export-server package but i can't able to find any perfect step to do , you're talking about normal download image with the help of axios but it's not working in case of highchart chart png

Comment: Axios download file with stream and writeFile will do the job [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55374755/node-js-axios-download-file-stream-and-writefile]

Comment: you are not getting my point exactly i haven't any fileUrl for download image I've highchart chart check my question again